# SQL: DELETE data from self-referencing table in specific order

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
groupId guid PK
parentId guid
name
left int
right int
```

There is a foreign key from parentId to groupId (this is a self-referencing table).

left and right are [MPTT](http://articles.sitepoint.com/print/hierarchical-data-database) left/right values for maintaining a hierarchy. The important thing to note here is the bigger the left value, the more deeply-nested an item is (in other words: for any given item, its left value will always be bigger than the left value of all parents).

---

I'm trying to write a quick DELETE statement to delete everything but the top-most group (which always has an empty GUID value), eg:

```
DELETE FROM [group] WHERE [groupId] <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'`
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, as there are generally sub-groups below any given group that prevent deletion. If you run that DELETE query over and over, eventually it will delete everything, but this is obviously not a good solution.

What I want is the equivalent of:

```
DELETE FROM [group] WHERE [groupId] <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' 
ORDER BY [left] DESC
```

Of course, that isn't allowed syntax, but effectively, it should delete the items with the largest left values first to ensure there are no groups below that will prevent deletion due to FK constraints.

I also tried:

```
delete from [group] where groupid in (
  select top 1000000 * from [group] 
  where groupid <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' 
  ORDER BY [left] desc
)
```

which is valid syntax (you can only use ORDER BY if you also use TOP) but doesn't actually cause the DELETE to happen in the order of returned rows, so it still doesn't work.

Is this possible to do, without resorting to a cursor to delete rows one-by-one?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ALTER TABLE [group] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
go
DELETE FROM [group] WHERE [groupId] <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
go
ALTER TABLE [group] CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
go
```

If the table is large, this might be a good option.

```
select * into #temptable from [group] WHERE [groupId] = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
go
truncate table [group]
go
select * into [group] from #temptable
go
drop table #temptable
go
```

Comment: +1 for disabling the constraint temporarily. As SQL Server still doesn't support deferrable constraints, disabling the FK is probably the quickest way to achieve this

Comment: This would be OK during development, but NEVER in production code

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the FK, do the delete, then put the FK back when you are done?  Kinda feels like cheating, but it might get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try disabling the constraint check:

```
CHECK / NOCHECK CONSTRAINT
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
declare @idgroup guid;
set @idgroup = 'whatever';

WITH n AS
(
    SELECT groupId, parentId
        FROM Table WHERE groupId=@idgroup
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.groupId, e.parentId
        FROM Table e JOIN n ON n.groupId=e.parentId
)
--Unlike some other systems, we don’t have to worry about the order the records are deleted, 
--since all SQL Server referential constraints are deferred till the end of the query.
DELETE FROM Table
WHERE groupId IN (SELECT groupId FROM n)
```

This will delete a specific group and all of its descendants with no worries about FK Constraint and order

Also there's a really good article about referential integrity and cascade actions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902684%28SQL.80%29.aspx)