# SQL Server 2008 Delete Records from Self-Referencing Table in correct order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, sql-delete, self-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: DELETE data from self-referencing table in specific order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200488/sql-delete-data-from-self-referencing-table-in-specific-order)

I need to delete a sub set of records from a self-referencing table in SQL Server 2008. I am trying to do the following but it is does not like the order by.

```
WITH SelfReferencingTable (ID, depth)
AS
(
   SELECT id, 0 as [depth]
   FROM dbo.Table
   WHERE parentItemID IS NULL AND [t].ColumnA = '123'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT [t].ID, [srt].[depth] + 1 
   FROM dbo.Table t 
   INNER JOIN SelfReferencingTable srt ON [t].parentItemID = [srt].id
   WHERE [t].ColumnA = '123'       
)   
DELETE y FROM dbo.Table y
JOIN SelfReferencingTable x on x.ID = y.id
ORDER BY x.depth DESC
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to delete them in any particular order.

Just delete them all in one operation. The constraints are checked at the end of the statement.

Assuming that your recursive CTE code correctly identifies all the rows that you need to delete you can just use

```
WITH SelfReferencingTable (ID)
AS
(
   SELECT id
   FROM dbo.Table
   WHERE parentItemID IS NULL AND [t].ColumnA = '123'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT [t].ID 
   FROM dbo.Table t 
   INNER JOIN SelfReferencingTable srt ON [t].parentItemID = [srt].id
   WHERE [t].ColumnA = '123'       
)   
DELETE 
FROM dbo.Table 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT id FROM SelfReferencingTable )
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried this but I was still getting problems... turned out to be a problem with the table data integrity. Once I ran DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS(Table) it found a record with a parentItemID that did not exist that was causing me issues.

Answer (score 0):

A `delete` clause doesn't allow an `order by`.  The `delete` is a single atomic operation, and it does not matter in which order the steps of the `delete` operation are completed.

An common solution is to delete rows with no dependent rows in a loop:

```
while 1=1
    begin
    delete  yt
    from    YourTable yt
    where   where ColumnA = '123'
            and not exists
            (
            select  *
            from    YourTable yt2
            where   yt2.parentItemId = yt.id
            )

    if @@rowcount = 0
        break
    end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just delete the parents with no children? I need to delete all records with ColumnA = '123' regardless if they are a parent or a child.

Comment: This will remove all records with no children records.  Then it loops through, and removes the next round of records which no longer have children records because of the last round of deletions.  This process continues until every record has been removed (unless a record has a self-referencing parent/child relationship).

Comment: Added the condition for ColumnA.  Note that if a record with `ColumnA = '123'` has children with a different ColumnA, those records cannot be removed.